# using python join to join first element of each list

Tags: python, join

I'd like to do this:

```
for qb in qb_data:
    qb_in += "'" + qb[0] + "'" + ","
```

using a join. Obviously the problem is that join just concatenates each member of the list. But here I have a list of lists and only need to join the first element of each list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
",".join("'%s'" % qb[0] for qb in qb_data)
```

You can still selectively pick out stuff in your generator expression/list comprehension, of course!

For example:

```
>>> qb_data = [['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
>>> ",".join("'%s'" % qb[0] for qb in qb_data)
"'1','3','5','7'"
```

Comment: I'm guessing that since the generator has to select the first element of each list, the gain in performance from using the join is offset? Obviously i'd have to use a profiler to know for sure. But what do you think?

Comment: @Daniel This will not work in case there is a None in the place of qb[0] or on an empty list within the list. String join needed a conditional expression there.

Comment: @thiruvenkadam, so can you explain how to deal with that?

Comment: @MattPsyK As I said, we need to add if within the String join, like ",".join("'%s'" % qb[0] for qb in qb_data if qb and qb[0])